# Add stickers with API

Tags: java, android

I am creating application for add stickers pack to whatsapp keyboard. i am done it with assets folder and JSON file from assets folder. but i want to add stickers from api to keyboard without use of assets folder.

Comment: Welcome to SO . Please explain whats your problem with code effort . Read [ask].

Comment: i want to add stickers dynamically from api. in present i was put all stickers in assets folder and generate json file to add stickers to whatsapp keyboard.

Comment: are you trying to add stickers through any web service or picking from device's camera/gallery ?

Comment: through web service